# Search the string from list to store in the list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am stored the list of channels in the list. I would like to search for the channel in the list with the matched string to see if I can fetching up to 7 channels.

Example: When my variable `channel` show `102 BBC Two`, I want to fetch `102 BBC Two`, `103 ITV`, `104 Channel`, `105 Channel`, `106 Sky One`, `107 Sky Living` and `108 Sky Atlantic` from the list so I can do something to store in the `channels_list` list.

Here is the code:

```
self.channel = ['101 BBC One S East', '102 BBC Two', '103 ITV', '104 Channel 4', '105 Channel 5', '106 Sky One', '107 Sky Living', '108 Sky Atlantic', '401 Sky Sports 1 UK', '402 SKY Sports 2 UK', '403 Sky Sports 3 UK', '404 Sky Sports 4 UK', '405 Sky Sports 5 UK', '406 Sky Sports News HQ', '407 Sky Sports F1', '408 Sky Sports 1 HD', '409 Sky Sports 2 HD', '410 Sky Sports 3 HD', '411 Sky Sports 4 HD', '412 Sky Sports 5 HD', '413 Eurosport 1 UK', '414 Eurosport 2 UK', '415 BT Sport 1', '416 BT Sport 2', '417 At the Races', '418 BT Sport ESPN', '419 MUTV', '420 Chelsea TV', '421 Eir Sport 1', '422 Eir Sport 2']

channel = "102 BBC Two"
channels_list = list()
#Store the 7 selected channels in the channels_list
```

Here is the list of elements:

```
['101 BBC One S East', '102 BBC Two', '103 ITV', '104 Channel 4', '105 Channel 5', '106 Sky One', '107 Sky Living', '108 Sky Atlantic', '401 Sky Sports 1 UK', '402 SKY Sports 2 UK', '403 Sky Sports 3 UK', '404 Sky Sports 4 UK', '405 Sky Sports 5 UK', '406 Sky Sports News HQ', '407 Sky Sports F1', '408 Sky Sports 1 HD', '409 Sky Sports 2 HD', '410 Sky Sports 3 HD', '411 Sky Sports 4 HD', '412 Sky Sports 5 HD', '413 Eurosport 1 UK', '414 Eurosport 2 UK', '415 BT Sport 1', '416 BT Sport 2', '417 At the Races', '418 BT Sport ESPN', '419 MUTV', '420 Chelsea TV', '421 Eir Sport 1', '422 Eir Sport 2']
```

Can you please show me an example how I can find the matched channel in the list with the string so I can fetch the 7 channels to store in the `channels_list` list?

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far?

Comment: What's the criteria for fetching those channels?

Comment: @thatrockbottomprogrammer I havent try anything so far as I dont know how to find the matched element from the list to start from there and fetchings 7 elements from the list. Can you please show me an example how I could do that?

Comment: But you got to know the criteria for matching. Is this a homework or a task?

Comment: This is my homework but I am sorry I dont know how to criteria for matching so you would have to help me how to criteria for matching in the list.

Comment: Please refer to your educational materials for examples on how to locate a value in a list.  I expect that you want the `index` method or the `in` operator.

Comment: You seem to be confusing "criteria" with some other word.  Once you've found `channel` in the list, what determines the channels you return?  There are many in the list, but you seem to have some selection criterion that reduces the list to 7 elements.

Comment: @Prune yes of course I want the `index` method but I don't know how to find the next 6 elements after the `102 BBC Two`. Do you know how I can fetch the next 6 elements from the list that come with `102 BBC Two` when I use `index` method?

Comment: The index returns the position of the element; call it `n`.  Your seven elements are at indices `n` through `n+6`.  This would be the sequence *slice* `channel[n:n+7]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `enumerate` to keep track of the index, then just compare the position.

```
for i, start_ch in enumerate(self.channel):
    if start_ch == channel:
        return self.channel[i:i+7]
```

Once you've found the right starting point, return a slice from the starting index to the starting index+7.

Comment: this is what I am looking for. Thank you very much for this. Problem are now solved!!!